# Detail error message

Tags: iis, asp-classic, error-handling

On my goddaddy plesk server when i try to open pages with database connections i get this error: http application failed. i have a web.config inside my folder but it doesn't seem to give me the right error message. i don't know if there's something wrong with my web.config file. here is it:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>

        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
        <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <compilation debug="true"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Is this [tag:asp.net] or [tag:asp-classic]? I know you've tagged it [tag:asp-classic] but I've learned not to trust those as they are often confused and there is no indication in your question this is a [tag:asp-classic] issue.